# i'm having trouble with importing pandas into my python script

Tags: python, pandas, macos

i've just installed pandas in terminal and as a package on PyCharm, and i'm having a problem. i just tried to do

```
import pandas as pd
```

it doesn't seem to work, and i get the error:

```
Python(27317,0x7fffa40d2380) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=18446744072140570624) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
init_dgelsd failed init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/CSVpractice/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/CSVpractice/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/CSVpractice/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 286, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Polyfit sanity test emitted a warning, most likely due to using a buggy Accelerate backend. If you compiled yourself, see site.cfg.example for information. Otherwise report this to the vendor that provided NumPy.
RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned
```

can anyone help? i don't know what to do. i'm on mac btw.

Comment: It looks like this is a problem with mac and specific versions of numpy (pandas requires numpy, so pip probably installed that. Numpy, in turn, needs a "backend" c or fortran library for the numerical computation. You are using the Accellerate backend. You should use OpenBlas). https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15947 I can't help further from there I don't use mac. But read that thread.

Comment: could you uninstall and install again by pip3 install numpy==1.18.0

Comment: ok i'll give that a try

Comment: ok, i tried re installing under an earlier version and it seems to be working, thanks!